# Kile crashing on typing in a file

Tags: crash, editing, kile

After start of Kile, I type a letter in the editor (last edited file opened), and the application crashed immediately. If instead of typing a letter, I open a new file and start typing in it, Kile is OK, but when I come back to the older file, again, after typing a letter it crashes.

It happened to me before and I managed to solve it, but I do not remember exact steps what helped. I think once I invoked the PDFLaTeX or LaTeX compilation as the first step, and after they had finished, the editing worked. Another time, that solution did not help, but running sudo kile or kile from CLI removed the problem. I do not understand why, but it helped.

I run KDE upon Ubuntu 14.04.

Does anyone know more about it? Any similar experience?

Comment: That's hard to debug as it is not possible to reproduce the crash when launched from terminal. But in such case you can trace it using `sudo strace -p PID`  when launched from menu/GUI. Anyway, you have already upgraded this machine. right? (from your other question)